# How to Upgrade Ionic3 to Ionic4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I have a couple of ionic 3 framework projects and templates, I wish to upgrade them to the current version of ionic which is now Ionic 4,

I keep getting errors when I do  *npm install*  or run  *ionic serve*

Comment: so upgrade is not so trivial actually and depends on your projects. did you try following the guide? https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/migration

Comment: rewrite code, because many things are different in ionic 4 then ionic 3. ex. routs, pass value, CSS etc...

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the easiest path is to identify each breaking change step by step using, this document: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/angular/BREAKING.md#breaking-changes

The migration linter is really handy as well: https://github.com/ionic-team/v4-migration-tslint